# $2$-dimensional Runge-Kutta for system of polynomial ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

I have just started getting into ODEs, and have come across the Runge-Kutta method for numerically solving them. However, in playing around with them to model hypothetical situations, I came across the equations:

$$\begin{aligned} \dot x &= x - x^2 - y\\ \dot y &= xy - y^2 \end{aligned}$$

I was trying to think of how one would use Runge Kutta methods to do this, and I couldn't figure it out. What is this type of differential equation called, and how can I simulate/solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The [Runge-Kutta formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods) for a system of differential equations are really the same as for a single equation, it's just that your dependent variable is a vector rather than a scalar.  Write your system as 
$$\dfrac{dX}{dt} = F(t, X(t))$$
where $X = (x, y)$.  If you're using the classical fourth-order Runge-Kutta with step size $h$, your iteration is
$$ \eqalign{K_1 &= h F(t_n, X_n)\cr
            K_2 &= h F(t_n + h/2, X_n + K_1 /2)\cr
            K_3 &= h F(t_n + h/2, X_n + K_2 /2)\cr
            K_4 &= h F(t_n + h, X_n + K_3)\cr
            t_{n+1} &= t_n + h\cr
            X_{n+1} &= X_n + (K_1 + 2 K_2 + 2 K_3 + K_4)/6\cr}$$

Comment: So what would $F$ be for OP's question?

Comment: $F(t, (x,y)) = (x - x^2 - y, x y - y^2)$.

Comment: but RHS is $(x−x^2−y,xy−y^2)=(\frac {dx}{dt},\frac {dy}{dt})$. Why is this the same as LHS?

Comment: What do you mean?  $ x - x^2 - y$ is the first entry of $F(t,X)$, and that is the derivative of the first entry of $X$, i.e. $dx/dt$.  $xy - y^2$ is the second entry of $F(t,X)$, and that is the derivative of the second entry of $X$, i.e. $dy/dt$.